# Amazon S3 invalid date when using expires in url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I create a document in an Amazon s3 bucket.  I then try to create a signed url to that bucket that expires a few years from now as follows:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => S3Config.access_key_id, :secret_access_key => S3Config.secret_access_key)
    bucket = s3.buckets[S3Config.bucket]
    bucket.objects[s3_key].url_for(:read, :expires => Time.at(Time.utc(2019,12,30)).to_i)
```

But when I navigate to the signed url I get the following error message:

```
Invalid date (should be seconds since epoch)
```

But according to the ruby docs for [Time.at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-c-at), and my understanding of epoch time, this should work...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception text may be coming from something deeper and ends up misleading, the docs and examples state:

> **:expires** (Object) — Sets the expiration time of the URL; after this time S3 will return an error if the URL is used. **This can be an integer (to specify the number of seconds after the *current time*)**, a string (which is parsed as a date using Time#parse), **a Time, or a DateTime object**. This option defaults to one hour after the current time.

Based on that, I think you're doing too much work, try this:

```
expires: Time.utc(2019, 12, 3)
```