# Invalid Date When Uploading to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 via putObject and a pre-signed URL.

Here is the URL that was provided when I generated the pre-signed URL:

`https://<myS3Bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/1ffd1c88-5661-48f9-a135-04bd569614dd.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=<accessKey>&Expires=1458177431311&Signature=<signature>-amz-security-token=<token>`

When I attempt to upload the file via a PUT, AWS responds with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid date (should be seconds since epoch): 1458177431311</Message>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is the curl version of the request I was using:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 78e46be3-8ecc-   4156-be3d-7e2f4688a127" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "file=@[object Object]" "https://<myS3Bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/1ffd1c88-5661-48f9-a135-04bd569614dd.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=<accessKey>&Expires=1458177431311&Signature=<signature>-amz-security-token=<mySecurityToken>"
```

Since the timestamp is generated by AWS, it should be correct.  I have tried changing it to include decimals and got the same error.

Could the problem be in the way I'm uploading the file in my request?

**Update - Add code for generating the signed URL**

The signed URL is being generated via the AWS Javascript SDK:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var uuid = require('node-uuid')
var Promise = require('bluebird')

var s3 = new AWS.S3()
var params = {
  Bucket: bucket,  // bucket is stored as .env variable
  Key: uuid.v4() + '.jpg' // file is always a jpg
}

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
    if (err) {
      reject(new Error(err))
    }
    var payload = { url: url }
    resolve(payload)
  })
})
```

My access key and secret key are loaded via environment variables as `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Comment: How did you generate this URL?  The `Expires=` time is clearly wrong and in a fairly obvious way: it represents the epoch time for `2016-03-17T01:17:11.311Z` ... multiplied by 1000 ... as if it was generated by code using time in milliseconds rather than time in seconds.  It would "work" if you just removed the last three digits, but you should find and fix the real issue.

Comment: I am using the SDK for Node to generate the URL and set the expires option when I sent the request for the signed URL.  I removed that and opted for the default which eliminated this error.  However, it now says that the request signature does not match the signature provided.  Do you have any insight into what that might be?

Comment: Please show your node code, including how you are the expires option.

Comment: I've updated the question above with the code that generates the signed URL.  I've confirmed that my access key and secret key do not have extraneous spaces in the `.env` file.

When I make the request using the URL, my file is attached as form-data with a `file` key.  Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Don't get distracted -- it's not going to be stray spaces in the keys.  Where, in this code, are you specifying the expiration time?

Comment: I removed it from the code above since it wasn't really adding that much value for me anyhow.  It was set using `Date.now() + 3600` inside the `params` object.  After removing it and attempting to send the request, I got the error `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Answer (score 2):

**Amazon S3 only supports 32 bit timestamps in signed urls:**

**2147483647** is the largest timestamp you can have.

I was creating timestamps 20 years in the future and it was breaking my signed URL's. Using a value less than 2,147,483,647 fixes the issue.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You just get bitten by bad documentation. Seems relate to this link

[Amazon S3 invalid date when using expires in url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203521/amazon-s3-invalid-date-when-using-expires-in-url-for)

The integer are mean for " (to specify the number of seconds **after the current time**)". 
Since you enter the time in epoch(0 = 1970-1-1), So it is current epoch time + your time, 46+46 years= 92 years. Appear to be crazy expiration period for s3.

Comment: That answer is does not appear to be relevant -- it is unrelated to the actual S3 API and only applies to the ruby implementation.  The `Expires=` value in the URL is the absolute epoch time, not the number of seconds after the current time.  The `Expires=` time in the link above appears to be an incorrectly-calculated value by a factor of 1000.